# Excel TEXT function doesn't work

Tags: excel

I tried to convert a date 1130505 to excel date format 5/5/2013, I first converted it by "=19000000+1130505"(20130505) in B2, then use =TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd") but it gave me an error. Anyone knows why?

[image: Attached pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking for a number in the excel date notation.  i.e. (see below) if you put in the date 8/7/2013 the excel "value" of that is 41493 for which the `=TEXT(B6,"yyyy-mm-dd")` formula would work.

[image]

Since you've already got the date formatted you don't want excel to do any thinking so you want to use `=TEXT(B2,"####-##-##")`

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(2000+MID(A1,2,2),MID(A1,4,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Then you can format **B1** (*if you need a true date)*:

[image]

or you can use:

```
=TEXT(DATE(2000+MID(A1,2,2),MID(A1,4,2),RIGHT(A1,2)),"m/d/yyyy")
```

if you need a *text* result.

Comment: Yes I know this method but it's too hard for my colleague to understand so I am looking for a simple way to do it. Thank you very much as well!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has values for dates that don't equate to the numbers concatenated, so unfortunately the "TEXT" formula isn't going to work.

My recommendation would be to use a combination of "CONCATENATE", "RIGHT", and "LEFT" functions. In this case, you'd write:
    `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,4),2),"/",RIGHT(A2,2),"/",RIGHT(LEFT(A2,3),2))`

It looks a bit complicated, but it's the only way I can think of to handle the ordering in your values and that leading "1".